# Singapore visa was rejected

Tags: visas, singapore

I was a student in Singapore and I was going to get an intership for 6 months but I canceled my work pass one week before the date of expiry and 15 days to exit from Singapore. One of my Singaporean friends applied for me but I got rejected. I already applied for SPASS but it takes 3 weeks to get it and I want to come really soon. I want to apply for a tourist visa and it’s already one month after my first rejected visa and also I have mail from the CTH saying that I still have an exam to do in December but I’m scared that if I apply again, I will get rejected again. Can you advise me?

Comment: Can you please explain clearly what exactly happened and what you're looking to do?  Why were you in Singapore on a Work Pass if you were a student, why did you cancel the pass before the end of your studies, what visa did your Sg friend apply for and why, and why isn't your school sponsoring the visa for your exam?  Have you asked the school what to do?

Comment: yes i was student and after that i had intership so they change u pass student pass to work training pass but i cancel my work tra pass before 1 weeks of expired date but with the agreement of my intership boss because i have some emergency i need to exsit singapore and after 15 days of my exsit my singaporean friend they apply for me tourist visa but they ICA rejected now its alredy one month i want to apply again but im scared to get rejected again but i have one mail from CTH school i still have exam i need to do in decembre im asking if i can apply now or i wait

Comment: You should not be applying as a tourist if you are coming for the exam.  You need to ask the school what they recommend and if they can sponsor your application.

Comment: that problems my school doesnt help us they just send mail about decembre exam i try to conatct them again and send mail but no answer

Comment: Either call them or try using some punctuation, because your messages are very difficult to read.